# TYPO3: get media content for special language

Tags: php, media, image, typo3

I want to get the picture of a certain page (the user set it on the tab "Resources"). For my default language I can use the media field of

```
$rootline =$GLOBALS['TSFE']->rootLine ;
```

But for my secondary language the media field is empty. The reason is the page translation I added which has its own settings. But now I need the media field for my default language.

How do I get the contents of rootline for a special language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->all['rootLine'][1]['media']
```

But then you need to know the level of the page within the page tree, so this is not a very practical solution.

The easiest way I see is a simple SQL query:

```
$row = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_fetch_assoc($GLOBALS['TYPO3_DB']->sql_query("SELECT media FROM pages WHERE uid = ".$GLOBALS['TSFE']->id));
$mediaFiles = $row['media'];
```